# C/C++ function using float or double or int

Tags: c++, c, text, io

I have seperate functions for reading from a text file (depending on whether its an int,  float or double). I would like just **one** function with an additional argument (without using a subsequent IF statement). Does anyone have ideas?

Below is the form of my current functions.

```
float * read_column_f (char * file, int size_of_col){
...
col = (float*) malloc (height_row * sizeof(float));
...  return(col);}


double *    read_column_d (char * file, int size_of_col){
...
col = (double*) malloc (height_row * sizeof(double));
...  return(col);}


int *   read_column_i (char * file, int size_of_col){
...
col = (int*) malloc (height_row * sizeof(int));
...  return(col);}
```

EDIT: I want to implement this in C++, the C-style syntax used is due to memory preference.

Comment: I removed the C++ tag, as, well, the extant IOStreams and function overloading if you wanted to do this without them, plus the code styles pretty much guarantees that this is C-only code.

Comment: Should use `const char *file` most likely.

Comment: does size_of_col refer to the size of the value (float,double,int) you are passing to the function?

Comment: size_of_col  = number of entries within the column,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't overload on return types. You either return value by reference as a function parameter:

```
void read_column (char * file, int size_of_col, float&);
void read_column (char * file, int size_of_col, int&);
```

...

or create a template:

```
template<class T> T read_column (char * file, int size_of_col);
```

Comment: Is that possible with just the return type being templated?

Comment: It is possible to only template the return type, but you will be left with something that is not that much better than multiple functions with different names, as the compiler will not be able to deduct the return type for you. User code will look like: `double d = read_column<double>( "file.txt", 10 );` --i.e. user code will have to make the type explicit.

Comment: @user502515: yes. It will be called as `read_column<int>`, `read_column<float>` or `read_column<double>`. It's considerably better than multiple functions with different names, because there's single source for all three functions, using `T` in place of the type to be read.

Comment: in your first option, the last parameter needs to be `float*&`, I think, because (for whatever reason) the questioner's function returns a pointer to a malloced array.

Comment: Presumably you could combine the two approaches, and use a template that takes a reference `T*&`.

Answer (score 6):

ANSI C doesn't support function overloading, which is what you are trying to accomplish.  C++ does, however.  See the StackOverflow link here: [Default values on arguments in C functions and function overloading in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2988038/default-values-on-arguments-in-c-functions-and-function-overloading-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

Use a template, like:

```
template<typename Type>
Type * read_column(char * file, int size_of_col)
{
    Type* col = (Type*) malloc(size_of_col * sizeof(Type));
    ...
    return(col);
}
```

Then call as so:

```
int    * col_int    = read_column<int>   ("blah", 123);
float  * col_float  = read_column<float> ("blah", 123);
double * col_double = read_column<double>("blah", 123);
etc.
```