# C++ header file with default arguments in C program

Tags: c++, c, header-files, default-value

I have a C++ library, with functions declared in a header file. My function declarations include default arguments.

I would like to use this library in Mathematica via the Wolfram Mathematica WSTP Template Compiler (wscc). This requires writing a C interface to my library. I have used this [pattern](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/mixing-c-and-cpp#include-c-hdrs-personal)

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

double my_function(double x, double abs_error = 1E-3);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

to prevent name-mangling in my library (compiled with C++). But what about the default arguments? I don't think they're standard C. From Wolfram Mathematica WSTP Template Compiler (wscc), I find

> error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘=’ token
>                    double abs_error = 1E-3,

Do I have to make separate C and C++ declarations (essentially two header files)? Is this a common problem or is it related to my use of wscc? Perhaps wscc doesn't support this syntax, although it is usually acceptable?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

[C does not support default arguments.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9185500/23649)

I'm therefore assuming you want to keep them for your C++ code, but you're okay with requiring C callers (in your case, Mathematica) to pass values for all arguments.

One possible approach is to define a macro which expands to the default value initializer in C++, but to nothing in C. It's not pretty, but it works:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define DEFAULT_VALUE(x) = x
#else
#define DEFAULT_VALUE(x)
#endif

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void foo(int x DEFAULT_VALUE(42), void *y DEFAULT_VALUE(nullptr));

// In C, this becomes   void foo(int x, void *y);
// In C++, this becomes void foo(int x = 42, void *y = nullptr);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Answer (score 1):

Rather than macro hackery to work around the fact that C does not support default arguments, I'd introduce a layer of indirection.

First a C++ specific header that your C++ code uses (which I arbitrarily name `interface.h`.

```
 double my_function_caller(double x, double abs_error = 1E-3);
```

and a C specific header (which I arbitrarily name `the_c_header.h`)

```
 double my_function(double x, double abs_error);

 /*  all other functions that have a C interface here */
```

In practice, one would probably want include guards in both headers.

The next step is a C++ compilation unit (which I arbitrarily name `interface.cpp`) that actually interfaces to mathematica

```
 #include "interface.h"

 extern "C"     //  this is C++, so we don't need to test __cplusplus
 {
      #include "the_c_header.h"
 }

 double my_function_caller(double x, double error)
 {
      return my_function(x, error);
 }
```

Then there is just the question of how to call the function.  If the caller is C++, then all it needs to do is

```
  #include "interface.h"

  //   and later in some code

       double result = my_function_caller(x);
       double another_result = my_function_caller(x, 1E-6);
```

If the caller is C (built with a C compiler) it simply does

```
  #include "the_c_header.h"

  /*  and later */

       result = my_function(x, 1E-3);
       another result = my_function(x, 1E-6);
```

There are obviously advantages and disadvantages of this, compared with a macro-based solution, including;

- None of the traditional disadvantages of macros (not respecting scope, no unintended interactions with other macros, running afoul of some C++ development guidelines that forbid usage of macros for anything except include guards).
- Clear separation of which code is C and which is C++: Only `interface.cpp` needs to take care to have both `#include "the_c_header.h"` and `#include "interface.h"` and worry about the mechanics of interfacing of C++ to C.   Otherwise, C compilation units (compiled with a C compiler) only need `#include "the_c_header.h"` and C++ compilation units only need to `#include "interface.h"`.
- `interface.h` can use any C++ language features (not just default arguments).  For example, all the functions it declares may be placed in a namespace named `mathematica` if you wish.   C++ developers using your functions need not care that there is actually an interface to C code buried away within that call.
- If you decide in future to re-implement `my_function()` using something other than mathematica you can.   Simply drop in the replacements of `the_c_header.h` and `interface.cpp`, and rebuild.  The separation of concerns means that it is unnecessary to change `interface.h`, that all C++ callers will not even need to be recompiled in an incremental build (unless, of course, you change `interface.h` for some other reason).
- Practically, the build process will detect mistaken usage of both header files.  A C compiler will choke on `interface.h` because it uses C++-specific features.   A C++ compiler will accept contents of `the_c_header.h` outside of an `extern "C"` context, but the result will be a linker error if any C++ code ever calls `my_function()` directly (linking will require a name-mangled definition).

In short, this takes a little more effort to set up than the macro approach, but is easier to maintain in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

The extern C does more than stop name mangling. The function has C calling conventions. It's telling the CPP compiler "you should now speak C". That means exceptions won't propagate, etc. And AFAIK C doesn't have default values.

You can have a function with C calling conventions implemented inside a CPP file, which is very useful sometimes. You can have C calling bits of your CPU code, which is useful.

My suspicion is that how a compiler goes about dealing with default values is up to the compiler writer. If that's true, I can think of at least a couple of ways, one of them not involving putting a value for `abs_error` on the stack when `my_function` is called. For example the compiler might include a parameter count on the stack which the function itself uses to spot that `abs_error` has not been passed and to set a default value. However such a compiler would be very unfriendly indeed if it did that with a function that had C calling conventions without reporting errors. I think I'd test it, just to be sure.

Comment: _"how a compiler goes about dealing with default values is up to the compiler writer"_ — I don't believe that's true...

Comment: @jtbandes, I looked for something definitive on that topic, and came up with nothing, hence my cautious words. My usual reference of choice is silent on the matter. I would welcome a definitive link! If it is defined in the draft c++14 standard it is not making itself massively obvious in section 8.3.6. I haven't fully worked out what the consequences of 8.3.6.5 mean to compiler implementers.