# Default arguments for pointer in C++ and mixed programming

Tags: c++, pointers, fortran, default-arguments, mixed-programming

The usage of default arguments for pointers in C++ can be demonstrated with following code

```
#include <iostream>

void myfunc_(int var, double* arr = 0) {
  if (arr == 0) {
    std::cout << "1 arg" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "2 arg" << std::endl;
  }
}

int main() {
  myfunc(1);
  double *arr = new double[2];
  myfunc(1, arr);
}
```

in this case, the output of the program is

```
1 arg
2 arg
```

on the other hand, if i try to pass optional arguments from Fortran to C++, it does not work. The following example code demonstrates the sutiation

The **myfunc.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>

extern "C" void myfunc_(int var, double* arr = 0) {
  if (arr == 0) {
    std::cout << "1 arg" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "2 arg" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

and the **Fortran main program**

```
program main
use iso_c_binding

real*8 :: arr(2)

call myfunc(1)
call myfunc(1, arr)
end program main
```

and the mixed code (Fortran and C++) can be compiled using following command without any error

```
g++ -c myfunc.cpp
gfortran -o main.x myfunc.o main.f90 -lstdc++ -lc++
```

but the program prints

```
2 arg
2 arg
```

in this case. So, Is there any solution for this problem? Am i missing something in here? I think that using default arguments in mixed programming is not working as it expected but i need suggestion at this point.

Comment: Although the answer to the dupe is not accepted, I think it addresses your issue, in other words, you cannot have non-C features (like default parameters) when compiling/linking with `extern C`. Here are some ways of simulating it: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2988038/3093378

Comment: Using extern "C" will allow the linker bind fortran's myfunc(1) call to the function with 2 arguments.  But only 1 is supplied, big time UB.  You cannot do this, use a function with an other name like myfunc2().

Comment: @vsoftco I do not agree with duplicating this. The problem can be solved, just the optional argument part must be done in Fortran, it has support for this.

Comment: Thanks, I reopened it so feel free to add an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, you cannot have default values of parameters in `extern "C"` functions. However, you can have optional arguments in the Fortran interface of the function and call it exactly the way you want:

```
#include <iostream>
extern "C" void myfunc(int var, double* arr) { //removed the = 0 and renamed to myfunc
  if (arr == 0) {
    std::cout << "1 arg" << std::endl;
  } else {
    std::cout << "2 arg" << std::endl;
  }
}
```

In Fortran create an interface describing the  C(C++) function:

```
program main
use iso_c_binding

interface
  subroutine myfunc(var, arr) bind(C, name="myfunc")  
    use iso_c_binding
    integer(c_int), value :: var
    real(c_double), optional :: arr(*)
  end subroutine
end interface

!C_double comes from iso_c_binding
real(c_double):: arr(2)

call myfunc(1_c_int)
call myfunc(1_c_int, arr)
end program main
```

The key thing is the `optional` attribute in the interface. If you don't supply the optional array, a null pointer will be passed instead.

Also notice the `value` attribute to the `var` argument. It is necessary because the C++ function accepts the parameter by value.

Note: this is quite a recent addition as a [TS](ftp://ftp.nag.co.uk/sc22wg5/N1901-N1950/N1942.pdf) to the Fortran 2008 standard, but is widely supported.

Comment: thanks for your solution. is this supported in g++ and gfortran? did you tested it? i am asking because when i try to compile your code with the commands given in my initial post, it complains about _myfunc function (Undefined symbols for architecture ...) and did not compile.

Comment: @epsilon Yes it will work. Noice that I renamed _myfunc to myfunc and that I use `bind(C,name="myfunc")` Be sure to follow these details or leave _myfunc and use `bind(C,name="_myfunc")`.

Comment: Yes i know that the function name changed. It is weird and i am using your code without any change but it does not compile. I did not change anything in the function and the main program. do you think that there could be a issue of compiler version.

Comment: BTW, i am using Mac OS along with GNU compiler and i think that the issue could be related with the OS and compilers. So, i tested the code under CentOS (gcc version 4.4.7 20120313) and it gives following error, when i try to compile it `gfortran -o main.x main.f90 myfunc.o 
main.f90:5.34:

        subroutine myfunc(var, arr) bind(C, name="myfunc")  
                                  1
Error: Variable 'arr' at (1) cannot have the OPTIONAL attribute because procedure 'myfunc' is BIND(C)`. 
With Intel compiler the error is
`main.f90:(.text+0x49): undefined reference to `myfunc'`.

Comment: @epsilon GCC 4..4 is too old. But I just checked the exact above code with GCC 4.8 (note I changed 2 lines in the C++) and it works. I compile as `gfortran opt.cc opt.f90 -lstdc++`.  Maybe you call `_myfunc` somewhere else?

Comment: Okay. Thanks for your help. Now it is working. I was adding `#include <iostream>` but not `extern "C"`. Now, it compels and works without any problem. I think that missing `extern "C"` was causing the problem. Anyway, thanks for your help.