# Lazy, overloaded C++ && operator?

Tags: c++, boolean, operator-keyword, lazy-evaluation

I'm trying to implement my own boolean class, but cannot replicate native semantics for &&. The following contrived code demonstrates the issue:

```
#include <iostream>

class MyBool {
public:
    bool theValue;
    MyBool() {}
    MyBool(bool aBool) {theValue = aBool;}
    MyBool operator&& (MyBool aBool) {return theValue && aBool.theValue;}
};

bool f1() {std::cout &lt;&lt; "   First\n"; return false;}
bool f2() {std::cout &lt;&lt; "   Second\n"; return false;}

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    std::cout &lt;&lt; "Native &&\n";
    f1() && f2();
    std::cout &lt;&lt; "Overloaded &&\n";
    MyBool(f1()) && MyBool(f2());
    return 0;
}
```

When compiled and run, the result is:

```
Native &&
   First
Overloaded &&
   Second
   First
```

In other words, && on bools is lazy (as any C++ programmer would expect) but the overloaded && isn't (as this C++ programmer at least didn't expect).

Is there a way to make overloaded && lazy? I can find various full-on lazy evaluation schemes to provide Haskell-like functionality, but they seem like complete overkill for my use case.

Comment: By lazy you mean short circuit. Overloaded operators doesn't have short circuiting.

Comment: This problem is exactly why it is recommended not to overload the `&&` operator.

Comment: Note that the reason the overloaded operator cannot short-circuit is that `MyBool aBool` is passed into it as a parameter. So `MyBool(f2())` needs to be computed before the implementation of `operator&&` gets a chance to run. In theory you could write a template `operator&&` overload whose RHS is a functor that returns `MyBool`. Then call that functor only if the LHS evaluates true. Then in C++11 callers could write a lambda: `MyBool(f1()) && []() { return MyBool(f2()); }`. But in practice, don't do that -- lazy evaluation is pretty ugly when you have to explicitly specify it on every call.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should not overload `bool operator&&`, since you lose short circuit evaluation, as you have discovered.

The correct approach would be to give your class a bool conversion operator

```
class MyBool {
 public:
  bool theValue;
  MyBool() {}
  MyBool(bool aBool) : theValue(aBool) {}
  explicit operator bool() { return theValue; }
};
```

Note that explicit conversion operators require C++11 compliance. If you do not have this, have a look at the [safe bool idiom](http://www.artima.com/cppsource/safebool.html).

Comment: +1, but it should be noted that `explicit operator`s are a C++11 feature, and C++03 requires the Safe Bool idiom.

Answer (score 6):

> Is there a way to make overloaded && lazy?

No.

Answer (score 2):

You can make almost anything evaluate lazily with [the expression template idiom](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Expression-template), including but not limited to the operators whose built-in versions short-circuit. But that's more work than you need for this one case, since then your `MyBool` class would require a *lot* more code.

Comment: "You can make almost anything evaluate lazily" - that's misleading, as this approach only works for cooperating user-defined types. For example, for any `T* p;` and `myBool && ++p`, you can't short-circuit the increment.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want short-circuiting and are willing to sacrifice the operator syntax, you can rename your `operator&&` method to `_and`, define an `AND()` macro, and write `AND(x,y)` instead of `x&&y`.

```
#define AND(x,y) (x._and(x.theValue ? y : MyBool(false)))
```

With some [macro hacks](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8814003/543913) you can have `AND()` accept a variable number of parameters.

The `_and()` method here is not intended to be used "publicly" here but must be declared public since you can't `friend` a macro.

For something as simple as your `MyBool` class, this is probably unnecessary. But if you need your `operator&&` to have special side-effects like updating some state on `this`, then this gets the job done.