# Variadic macro and trailing comma

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, variadic-macros

I am trying to do object-orientation in C and want to have a syntactic sugar macro for the notation

```
object->vtable->method(object, arg1, arg2)
```

into

```
send(object, method, arg1, arg2)
```

Unfortunately when a method takes no argument, the trailing comma problem arises

```
send(object, method)
```

gives

```
object->vtable->method(object, )
```

Is there any ***portable*** (no `##__VA_ARGS__` or Visual Studio) way of doing this?

I figured out one but I need to swap the object and the method

```
#define FIRST_ARG_(N, ...) N
#define FIRST_ARG(args) FIRST_ARG_(args)
#define send(msg, ...) \
 FIRST_ARG(__VA_ARGS__)->vtable->msg(__VA_ARGS__)
```

permits

```
send(method, object)
send(method, object, arg1, arg2)
```

**Edit**

With the help of two good answers from below I will do it with these macros. It works up to 16 arguments but can easily be extended

```
#define SEND_NO_ARG(obj, msg) obj->vtable->msg(obj)
#define SEND_ARG(obj, msg, ...) obj->vtable->msg(obj, __VA_ARGS__)

#define GET_18TH_ARG(arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4, arg5, \
    arg6, arg7, arg8, arg9, arg10, arg11, arg12, arg13, arg14, arg15, \
    arg16, arg17, arg18, ...) arg18
#define SEND_MACRO_CHOOSER(...) \
    GET_18TH_ARG(__VA_ARGS__, \
            SEND_ARG, SEND_ARG, SEND_ARG, SEND_ARG, SEND_ARG, \
            SEND_ARG, SEND_ARG, SEND_ARG, SEND_ARG, SEND_ARG, \
            SEND_ARG, SEND_ARG, SEND_ARG, SEND_ARG, SEND_ARG, \
            SEND_NO_ARG, )

#define SEND(...) SEND_MACRO_CHOOSER(__VA_ARGS__)(__VA_ARGS__)
```

Comment: No, there isn't. That's why those extensions exist. :-(

Comment: `#define send(method, object, ...) object->vtable->method(object,##__VA_ARGS__)` is not portable ?

Comment: No it's a GCC extension

Comment: Here is a stack overflow question and answers on the subject of approaches for object oriented C source code.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/351733/can-you-write-object-oriented-code-in-c

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Optional Parameters with C++ Macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046889/optional-parameters-with-c-macros)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3048361/316448) there is technique explained which should allow you to count the number of parameters and use `object` and `method` as the first two arguments.

Comment: This is not  good answer as it doesn't provide the actual answer inline.   What if the linked answer gets deleted?

Answer (score 4):

Short answer, yes, it is possible in a portable way.

Long answer: it's complicated, and you probably don't want to implement this yourself. There are ways to count the arguments that a macro receives and then take action according to that number. [P99](http://p99.gforge.inria.fr) implements a series of macros that can help you to achieve this. If you'd implement two base macros `send_2` and `send_more` for the two cases you could then implement `send` as

```
#define send(...)                     \
 P99_IF_LT(P99_NARG(__VA_ARGS__), 3)  \
 (send_2(__VA_ARGS__))                \
 (send_more(__VA_ARGS__))
```

Technically these constructs in P99 have a restriction that they can't handle more than 150 (or so) arguments to `send`.

BTW, you know that probably, calling a macro `send` is not really a good idea. Usually people prefer that macros are in all-caps. Also most of the time it is a good idea to have a name prefix that is unique to your library/package, such as `AC245_SEND`.

Comment: How does this answer help me if p99 goes away?  It doesn't even provide information about the fundamental approach to counting argument