# Dynamic Dispatch to Template Function C++

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I have a template function (in my case a cuda kernel), where there are a small number of boolean template parameters that can chosen between at runtime. I am happy to instantiate all permutations at compile time and dispatch dynamically, like so (for boolean b0,b1,b2):

```
if (b0) {
    if (b1) {
        if (b2) {
            myFunc<true,true,true,otherArgs>(args);
        } else {
            myFunc<true,true,false,otherArgs>(args);
        }
    } else {
        if(b2) {
            myFunc<true,false,true,otherArgs>(args);
        } else {
            myFunc<true,false,false,otherArgs>(args);
        }
    }
} else {
    if(b1) {
        if(b2) {
            myFunc<false,true,true,otherArgs>(args);
        } else {
            myFunc<false,true,false,otherArgs>(args);
        }
    } else {
        if(b2) {
            myFunc<false,false,true,otherArgs>(args);
        } else {
            myFunc<false,false,false,otherArgs>(args);
        }
    }
}
```

This is annoying to write, and gets exponentially worse if I end up with a b3 and b4.

Is there a simple way to rewrite this in a more concise way in C++11/14 without bringing in large external libraries (like boost)? Something like:

```
const auto dispatcher = construct_dispatcher<bool, 3>(myFunc);
```

...

```
dispatcher(b0,b1,b2,otherArgs,args);
```

Comment: `func_array[4*b0+2*b1+b2](args)`, or even `func_array[b0][b1][b2](args)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No problem.

```
template<bool b>
using kbool = std::integral_constant<bool, b>;

template<std::size_t max>
struct dispatch_bools {
  template<std::size_t N, class F, class...Bools>
  void operator()( std::array<bool, N> const& input, F&& continuation, Bools... )
  {
    if (input[max-1])
      dispatch_bools<max-1>{}( input, continuation, kbool<true>{}, Bools{}... );
    else
      dispatch_bools<max-1>{}( input, continuation, kbool<false>{}, Bools{}... );
  }
};
template<>
struct dispatch_bools<0> {
  template<std::size_t N, class F, class...Bools>
  void operator()( std::array<bool, N> const& input, F&& continuation, Bools... )
  {
     continuation( Bools{}... );
  }
};
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/a7b8d1b13e41898e).

So `kbool` is a variable with represents a compile time constant boolean.  `dispatch_bools` is a helper struct that has an `operator()`.

This `operator()` takes an array of runtime `bool`s, and starting at `max-1` proceeds to spawn max if/else branches, each recursing into call to `dispatch_bools` with one more compile-time bool calculated.

This generates 2^max code; exactly the code you don't want to write.

The continuation is passed all the way down to the bottom recursion (where `max=0`).  At that point, all of the compile-time bools have been built up -- we call `continuation::operator()` passing in those compile-time bools as function parameters.

Hopefully `continuation::operator()` is a template function that can accept compile-time bools.  If it is, there are 2^max instantiations of it, each with each of the 2^max possible true/false combinations.

---

To use this to solve your problem in [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) you just do:

```
std::array<bool, 3> bargs={{b0, b1, b2}};
dispatch_bools<3>{}(bargs, [&](auto...Bargs){
  myFunc<decltype(Bargs)::value...,otherArgs>(args);
});
```

This is easy because [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) has `auto` lambdas; it can have a template `operator()` on a lambda.  Turning those compile-time bool arguments back into template non-type arguments is easy.

Note that many nominally [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) compilers support auto-lambdas, because of how easy it was.  However, if you lack it, you can still solve this in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) with a helper struct:

```
template<class OtherArgs>
struct callMyFunc {
  Args args;
  template<class...Bools>
  void operator()(Bools...){
    myFunc<Bools::value...,otherArgs>(args);
  }
};
```

now use is:

```
std::array<bool, 3> bargs={{b0, b1, b2}};
dispatch_bools<3>{}(bargs, callMyFunc<otherArgs>{args});
```

This is basically manually writing what the [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) lambda would do.

---

In [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) you can replace `void` with `auto` and return instead of just recursing and it will deduce a return type for you reasonably well.

If you want that feature in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11) you can either write a lot of `decltype` code, or you can use this macro:

```
#define RETURNS(...) \
  noexcept(noexcept(__VA_ARGS__)) \
  -> decltype(__VA_ARGS__) \
  { return __VA_ARGS__; }
```

and write the body of `dispatch_bools` like:

```
template<class T, std::size_t N, class F, class...Bools>
auto operator()( std::array<T, N> const& input, F&& continuation, Bools... )
RETURNS(
 (input[max-1])?
    dispatch_bools<max-1>{}( input, continutation, kbool<true>{}, Bools{}... )
 :
    dispatch_bools<max-1>{}( input, continutation, kbool<false>{}, Bools{}... )
)
```

and similar for the `<0>` specialization, and get [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) style return deduction in [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11).

`RETURNS` makes deducing return types of one-liner functions trivial.

Comment: Your formatting is off and your use of bool constants are slightly inconsistent (`Bools{}...`/`Bools::value...`) `decltype(Bargs)::value...` can be written as `Bargs...`. Or am I dumb and `this` is used in the conversion in C++11?

Comment: @PasserBy constexpr converstion to bool is a C++14 feature on integral constant.  And I never put `Bools::value...` in `()` only in `<>`.

Comment: [It's not](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n3337/meta.help). Do you mean `operator()`?

Comment: @PasserBy Hmm.  Maybe it was a bug in an old C++11 compiler; I remember it didn't work prior to an update in the compiler back then.

Comment: This is great, thanks! I'm getting some long warnings when doing this in VS2015 from unreferenced formal parameters to the <Bargs_2> (and 1 and 0, and the input in the base case specialization). Would you suggest just suppressing the warnings around the dispatch code?

Comment: @mike or create a `template<class...Ts>void ignored(Ts&&...){}` and call it.  It does nothing but should suppress the warnings.

Answer (score 3):

Is there a simple way? No. Can it be done using an unholy mess of garbled templates? Sure, why not.

## Implementation

First, this is going to be a bit easier if we have a class rather than a function, simply because parameterized classes can be passed as template parameters. So I'm going to write a trivial wrapper around your `myFunc`.

```
template <bool... Acc>
struct MyFuncWrapper {
  template <typename T>
  void operator()(T&& extra) const {
    return myFunc<Acc...>(std::forward<T&&>(extra));
  }
};
```

This is just a class for which `MyFuncWrapper<...>()(extra)` is equivalent to `myFunc<...>(extra)`.

Now let's make our dispatcher.

```
template <template <bool...> class Func, typename Args, bool... Acc>
struct Dispatcher {

  auto dispatch(Args&& args) const {
    return Func<Acc...>()(std::forward<Args&&>(args));
  }

  template <typename... Bools>
  auto dispatch(Args&& args, bool head, Bools... tail) const {
    return head ?
      Dispatcher<Func, Args, Acc..., true >().dispatch(std::forward<Args&&>(args), tail...) :
      Dispatcher<Func, Args, Acc..., false>().dispatch(std::forward<Args&&>(args), tail...);
  }

};
```

Whew, there's quite a bit to explain there. The `Dispatcher` class has two template arguments and then a variadic list. The first two arguments are simple: the function we want to call (as a class) and the "extra" argument type. The variadic argument will start out empty, and we'll use it as an accumulator during the recursion (similar to an accumulator when you're doing [tail call optimization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tail_call)) to accumulate the template Boolean list.

`dispatch` is just a recursive template function. The base case is when we don't have any arguments left, so we just call the function with the arguments we've accumulated so far. The recursive case involves a conditional, where we accumulate a `true` if the Boolean is `true` and a `false` if it's `false`.

We can call this with

```
Dispatcher<MyFuncWrapper, TypeOfExtraArgument>()
    .dispatch(extraArgument, true, true, false);
```

However, this is a bit verbose, so we can write a macro to make it a bit more approachable.<sup>1</sup>

```
#define DISPATCH(F, A, ...) Dispatcher<F, decltype(A)>().dispatch(A, __VA_ARGS__);
```

Now our call is

```
DISPATCH(MyFuncWrapper, extraArgument, true, true, false);
```

## Complete Runnable Example

Includes a sample `myFunc` implementation.

```
#include <utility>
#include <iostream>

#define DISPATCH(F, A, ...) Dispatcher<F, decltype(A)>().dispatch(A, __VA_ARGS__);

template <bool a, bool b, bool c, typename T>
void myFunc(T&& extra) {
  std::cout << a << " " << b << " " << c << " " << extra << std::endl;
}

template <bool... Acc>
struct MyFuncWrapper {
  template <typename T>
  void operator()(T&& extra) const {
    return myFunc<Acc...>(std::forward<T&&>(extra));
  }
};

template <template <bool...> class Func, typename Args, bool... Acc>
struct Dispatcher {

  auto dispatch(Args&& args) const {
    return Func<Acc...>()(std::forward<Args&&>(args));
  }

  template <typename... Bools>
  auto dispatch(Args&& args, bool head, Bools... tail) const {
    return head ?
      Dispatcher<Func, Args, Acc..., true >().dispatch(std::forward<Args&&>(args), tail...) :
      Dispatcher<Func, Args, Acc..., false>().dispatch(std::forward<Args&&>(args), tail...);
  }

};

int main() {
  DISPATCH(MyFuncWrapper, 17, true, true, false);
  DISPATCH(MyFuncWrapper, 22, true, false, true);
  DISPATCH(MyFuncWrapper, -9, false, false, false);
}
```

## Closing Notes

The implementation provided above will let `myFunc` return values as well, although your example only included a return type of `void`, so I'm not sure you'll need this. As written, the implementation requires C++14 for `auto` return types. If you want to do this under C++11, you can either change all the return types to `void` (can't return anything from `myFunc` anymore) or you can try to hack together the return types with `decltype`. If you want to do this in C++98, ... ... ... ... <sub><sub>good luck</sub></sub>

---

<sup>1</sup> This macro is susceptible to the [comma problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20818800/variadic-macro-and-trailing-comma) and thus won't work if you pass it zero Booleans. But if you're not going to pass any Booleans, you probably shouldn't be going through this process anyway.