# Passing brace enclosed initializer list to variadic macro and expanding to std::pair<>

Tags: c++, macros, initializer-list, variadic

I am currently working on a threaded Logging library as the first part of a bigger project for graphics drawing (for personal learning and development of skills).

currently i am using a singleton with a thread running on the side and taking Log messages and data into queues (so that they are not blocking events) to be processed later. I wrote a small wrapper around std::map<> as LogData that can be displayed by the logger in a stream or file in the following way.

```
[0.000155][DEBUG]: FILE LOGGER ADDED { ID="1" LVL="TRACE" }
```

The constructors allows to pass string,char*,floats,int,short long etc and will convert it to a string to be displayed later in thoses brackets.

Currently constructing this LogData is a bit bloaty. Example that produced the log above:

```
GG::LogData id_dat;
id_dat.push("ID", id);
id_dat.push("LVL",GG::loglevel_toString(lvl));
GG_DEBUG("FILE LOGGER ADDED", id_dat);
```

Since my Class is a Singleton i use macro's to allow for ease of use they are all the same as :

```
#define GG_TRACE(MESS, ...) GG::Logging::get()->push_to_queue(GG::LOG_LEVEL::TRACE, MESS, ##__VA_ARGS__);
```

This works fine for most use. But i wanted to make it possible to use on one line, and make it less bloaty. the effect i wanted to achieve was something like this :

```
//Desired Usage
GG_TRACE("VARIADIC TEST", {"X","1"}, {"Y","2"}, {"Z","3"});
```

this is expanded here:

```
void Logging::push_to_queue(GG::LOG_LEVEL level, std::string mess, std::pair<const char*, std::string> log_data ...)
```

I would use brace initialized list to produce the log data, then i would loop over the variadic argument and construct the LogData in a function instead of having to do it manually every time.

i had it working directly with a function like so.

```
void test(std::pair<char*,int> p) {
    GG::LogData dat;
    dat.push("key", p.first);
    dat.push("value", p.second);
    GG_TRACE("PAIR: ", dat);
}
// In main...
test({ "test",1 });
```

and that worked fine. But when i try to use that same pattern and have the macro's forward it to the push_to_queue fonction i get the following error with GCC.
[image: GCC compile error]

Anybody have ever used brace enclosed initializer list in this way or know how to fix this bug ? i am fairly new to this kind of pattern. Any other suggestion or pointers to improve on this is appreciated. (sorry for the long post)

Comment: In my experience (using Google test) macros and braced initializers don't play nice.

Comment: Wrong idea! Macros are processed before anything of c or c++ code is parsed. There is no trick to pass something from c++ back to macros. BTW: Stop using macros! We are in 2020 and it should be possible to write some simple function which takes any number of different types as you like,

Comment: @Klaus Any types ... but a braced initializer list doesn't have a type, and always means template argument deduction is skipped for the parameter/argument pair, so a straightforward variadic template won't be nice to use, at least with the desired syntax.

Comment: @Klaus Any suggestion, for adjustements ?

Comment: @aschepler what do you suggest i do in this case ? Stick with the macro's ? Any other pattern to suggest ?

Comment: Maybe something like: https://brevzin.github.io/c++/2019/12/02/named-arguments/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the declaration

```
void Logging::push_to_queue(GG::LOG_LEVEL level, std::string mess,
    std::pair<const char*, std::string> log_data ...);
```

does not have a variable number of parameters with type `std::pair<const char*, std::string>`. It's actually equivalent to the version with an added comma:

```
void Logging::push_to_queue(GG::LOG_LEVEL level, std::string mess,
    std::pair<const char*, std::string> log_data,
    ...);
```

which has one parameter of type `std::pair<const char*, std::string>`, and is a C-style variadic function, with arguments after the third only available via the `<cstdarg>` macros `va_start`, `va_arg`, and `va_end`. This can't be what you want, since there's no good way for such a function to know how many arguments there were, and since a braced list can never be an argument matching the C-style ellipsis.

The only way to get a C++-style variadic function which knows the number (and types) of arguments is as a template with a variadic template parameter. But a braced list as argument means no template argument deduction, so it would be tricky to make this nice to use.

But we can get this syntax working using a `std::initializer_list`, plus adding more `{}` in the macro:

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <utility>
#include <string>

void GG::Logging::push_to_queue(GG::LOG_LEVEL level, std::string mess,
    std::initializer_list<std::pair<const char*, std::string>> log_data)
{
    GG::LogData dat;
    for (const auto &kv : log_data)
        dat.push(kv.first, kv.second);
    // Do the rest...
}

#define GG_TRACE(MESS, ...) (GG::Logging::get()->push_to_queue( \
     GG::LOG_LEVEL::TRACE, MESS, {__VA_ARGS__}))
```

So the expansion will have an argument like `{{"X","1"}, {"Y","2"}, {"Z","3"}}`, where the outer `{}` are for the `std::initializer_list` and the inner `{}` for each `std::pair`.

Comment: That indeed worked as i woudl like to, the extra {} are indeed a bit less nice to use, but it is much nicer than the previous use. Thx.

But i used to be able to use the macro either :
GG_TRACE("some message")
or
GG_TRACE("some message", someLogData)

altho the use with logData or {{},{}}works, now the simple one without data does not. The compiler throws a call is ambiguous error

Comment: You don't need to type the extra `{}`, since the `GG_TRACE` adds them in. See example: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/90d6eee2954bdc45 Not sure of the cause of the "ambiguous" - are there other overloads?

Comment: Oh wow, thats great ! now i get what its doing thx ! But im stil trying to fix that ambiguous call thing..... right now im looking into this.... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3046889/optional-parameters-with-c-macros

Comment: somehow that macro does not work for me....it  either complains about a missing } or an ambiguous call to the overloaded push_to_queue function

Comment: somehow that macro does not work for me....well, It works when im adding the initializer_list, but the one with only a message does not work and throws a "overloaded push_to_queue is ambiguous" error

Comment: So there's more than one `push_to_queue` function?

Comment: yes there is, but i found the problem, my push_to_queue fonction didnt not have a const char* overload.

Comment: Also do you think it woudl be at all possible to overload that push_to_queue fonction multiple times to allows to pass the bracket enclosed initialized list with all the base type as values ?

Comment: This is getting too abstract for me to understand. Maybe you should post another question about the overloading issue.