# Why this error " pngrutil.c:27:error: expected ‘;’, ‘,’ or ‘)’ before ‘=’ token" in the following function?

Tags: c

```
double shrDelta(int iCounterID = 0){     //this is the 27  the line

    double DeltaT;            
    static struct timeval _NewTime;  
    static struct timeval _OldTime[3]; 
    gettimeofday(&_NewTime, NULL);  

    if (iCounterID >= 0 && iCounterID <= 2)
        {        

        DeltaT =  ((double)_NewTime.tv_sec + 1.0e-6 * (double)_NewTime.tv_usec) - ((double)_OldTime[iCounterID].tv_sec + 1.0e-6 * (double)_OldTime[iCounterID].tv_usec);        

        _OldTime[iCounterID].tv_sec  = _NewTime.tv_sec;     
        _OldTime[iCounterID].tv_usec = _NewTime.tv_usec;        
        }   
    else        
        {         

        DeltaT = -9999.0;       
        }     

    return DeltaT;
}
```

The function is supposed to return the time elapsed between last two calls.

Comment: You can't put an assignment in the parameter list of a function in C.

Comment: I think you're confusing C with some other languages that allow you to specify default arguments this way.

Comment: Generally it is good form to explain the issue you are getting and then ask a question in the body of the text.

Comment: the function is working fine in a cpp file, but i just copied the whole function in a .c file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C does not support defaulting of function parameters (or function overloading for that matter).

You need to write

`double shrDelta(int iCounterID)`

instead and always call the function with the parameter value explicitly given.

Answer (score 2):

C standard doesnt support default values. what you used is a C++ concept. you can read this related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472138/c-default-arguments)