# extern "C" Default argument works or not?

Tags: c++, c, arguments, extern

From [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472138/c-default-arguments) it seems that default argument are not supported by C.

I have the following method in exported library:

```
extern "C" 
{
    __declspec (dllexport) uintptr_t Method(int freq, int *pRetval, bool *support2MHz);
}
```

If i made last argument optional like this:

```
extern "C" 
{
    __declspec (dllexport) uintptr_t Method(int freq, int *pRetval, bool *support2MHz = NULL);
}
```

My dll is still compiled. **My question is why?** Everyone says the default arguments are not supported in C code.

I use C++ for MS 2015.

Comment: i think it works because default argument are handle by the caller

Comment: `extern "C"` does not mean "this is C code", it only affects the form of the exported symbols (i.e. "Method"). If you feed that to a C compiler, it will complain about both the `extern "C"` and the default argument.

Comment: As far as I know, when you try to use this export, you will still need to provide 3 parameters. this is c++, that's why you can provide default argument here, but when you try to use exported C function, you need to provide all 3.

Comment: @Afshin "use exported C function", you mean use the exported in C code or C++ code?

Comment: @John I mean when you want to use exported C++ code in a C code.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As molbdnilo already noted in the comments, `extern "C"` does not mean "this is C code", but "this is code with C linkage" - i.e. name mangling for this function will not be performed, so you will be able to call it from C with the "expected" function call syntax. C++ compilers mangle the names of functions so they can support function overloading, since symbol names of different overloads of the same function have to be unique (basically, they use function's scope, name and argument types to create a unique symbol name).

According to [**[dcl.fct.default]**](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.default), paragraphs 1 and 2 of the standard:

> If an *initializer-clause* is specified in a *parameter-declaration* this
>   *initializer-clause* is used as a default argument. Default arguments
>   will be used in calls where trailing arguments are missing.
>
> [Example: The declaration
>
> ```
> void point(int = 3, int = 4);
> ```
>
> declares a function that can be called with zero, one, or two arguments of type
>   `int`. It can be called in any of these ways:
>
> ```
> point(1,2); point(1); point();
> ```
>
> The last two calls are equivalent to `point(1,4)` and
>   `point(3,4)`, respectively. — end example ]

In addition, paragraph 9 specifies:

> A default argument is not part of the type of a function. [ Example:
>
> ```
> int f(int = 0);
>
> void h() {
>     int j = f(1);
>     int k = f();                      // OK, means f(0)
> }
>
> int (*p1)(int) = &f;
> int (*p2)() = &f;                   // error: type mismatch
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Thus, for a function with a default argument `int foo(int x, int y = 0)`, the compiler will not generate two overloads (`int foo(int x, int y)` and `int foo(int x)`, with `y` fixed to `0`), but instead replace every call of the form `foo(x)` with a call to `foo(x, 0)`. In your concrete example with `extern "C"` this means that the compiler generates only one symbol with C linkage for `Method` so there is no name clash.

You can see this behavior for various compilers in a [live example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/KME7uo).

However, as Afshin already mentioned in the comments, the way this is implemented makes it impossible to "propagate" default arguments to other users of your shared library, so if you want to use this from C, you'll still need to pass all arguments to the function.