# Calling C++ function with default parameters from Python

Tags: python, c++

I have exported this simple function from an DLL (Am working in MSVC2015, Windows 10, x64) :

```
// Main.h
#define DLL_SEMANTICS __declspec (dllexport)
extern "C"
{
    DLL_SEMANTICS int CheckVal(const int x, const int y = 1);

}
```

code:

```
// Main.cpp

    int CheckVal(const int x, const int y)
    { cout << y << endl; return 0; }

}
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50566076/extern-c-default-argument-works-or-not) SO thread using `extern "C"` shouldn't be a problem and indeed when
calling this function from an exe file I got the desired results (i.e., "1" to the console) but but when I called this from Python using:

```
import ctypes
from ctypes import cdll

dllPath = r"C:\MyDll.dll"
lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(dllPath)
lib.CheckVal(ctypes.c_int(1))
```

I am getting some garbage value being printed (Debugging via PTVS confirmed that `y` is indeed garbage value.)

Am I doing something wrong or defualt parameters cannot work from Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Default parameters are a nicety of C++. You need to pass two arguments if you're calling outside C++.