# Can I run a C function both with and without arguments?

Tags: c

Is it ok to leave the parameters unused?
I'm trying to run the function like this:

```
void encoder();
void encoder(int argc, FILE* inputFP, FILE* outputFP);
```

Is there a need for a second function, one for dealing with stdio and one for dealing with files? When I try to run
`void encoder(int argc, FILE* inputFP, FILE* outputFP);` without any arguments I get errors:

````
error: too few arguments to function â€˜void encoder(int, FILE*, FILE*)â€™
         encoder();```
````

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472138/c-default-arguments

Comment: No, it's not OK. The error message is explicit. Or rather it's not OK anymore since 20 years or so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it ok to leave the parameters unused?

No, all arguments must be present and correct.

You should also be careful that you do not provide different prototypes for a function (or any symbol) within a given application.

---

If you really want to call it with no arguments, then the best approach is to have two functions and call the one you're after:

```c
void encoder(void) {
    encoder2(0, stdin, stdout);
}

void encoder2(int argc, FILE* inputFP, FILE* outputFP) {
    /* ... */
}
```

---

If you want to have a variable number of arguments, then you could look at using the macros in [`stdarg.h`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stdarg.h) (like `printf()` and friends), though you still won't be able to get away with *zero* arguments, and you'll need to be very careful with your usage.

Comment: ..though you can have a convention that any argument that is not provided will be `NULL` or `0`.

Comment: Oh? Could you expand on that?

Comment: For example `encoder2(0,0,0)` means no arguments, use defaults `stdin` and `stdout`.

Comment: Oh I see, thanks... I thought you were implying that `encoder2(,,)` or similar would behave as `encoder2(0,0,0)`...(!)

Comment: Is it considered a good practice to allways pass void as an argument whenever you are going to run encoder() ? Or is it something that should be done in .h?

Comment: the prototype (`void encoder(void);`) is different to calling the function (`encoder();`). When declaring, the `void` is a _very good idea_, when calling you should not pass any arguments.

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, no it's not valid.

C lacks the support for default values, so the arguments would be quite useless. The solution to this particular problem is to use magic `FILE *` "files" that map to the standard input/output channels, i.e. `stdin` and `stdout` from [`<stdio.h>`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/stdio.3.html).

Comment: That description is a little vague for someone who can't distinguish between stdin, stdout and file handles.