# Calling function with macro in C

Tags: c, macros

I have function in C with 3 params. I want to call that function with pre-defined values. Is there any solution?

My idea which does not work.

```
#define PRE_DEFINED_MACRO   (10, 15 , true)

void myFunc(uint8_t temp, uint32_t value, bool valid)
{
  .... 
}
....
//call the function like that
myFunc(PRE_DEFINED_MACRO);
```

Comment: C and C++ are very different languages. Please don't tag both unless you're specifically asking about their differences.

Comment: Remove the "()" `#define PRE_DEFINED_MACRO  10, 15 , true`

Comment: If you expand the macro yourself, you find `myFunc((10, 15 , true));` which (obviously) has too many parentheses.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your macro already includes parentheses, so when this ...

> ```
> myFunc(PRE_DEFINED_MACRO);
> ```

... is expanded, the result is:

```
myFunc((10, 15 , true));
```

You could do this instead:

```
myFunc PRE_DEFINED_MACRO;
```

I find that pretty confusing, however.  Personally, I would prefer to remove the parentheses from the macro's replacement text:

```
#define MYFUNC_ARGS  10, 15 , true

// ...

myFunc(MYFUNC_ARGS);
```

That makes it much clearer that the call to `myFunc()` is, in fact, a function call.  The choice of macro name also makes the intended purpose of the macro much clearer.

Comment: Define the function in the header with only 1 argument, and make it call the one with 3 arguments. If the function with 3 arguments must always be called with predefined values, make it static inside the `. c` file, juste expose a function using each predefined parameters set, like a public method delegating to a private one. Don't use macros for what you can do without it, macros are more often source of mistakes.

Answer (score 1):

To just replace 3 arguments with a macro:

```
#define PRE_DEFINED_MACRO   10, 15, true
```

The reason why you can't use a parenthesis is because it would expand as `myFunc((10, 15, true));` and the compiler reads that as "the first parameter is obtained from a chained series of comma operators and the rest of the parameters are missing". [What does the comma operator , do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52550/what-does-the-comma-operator-do)

As for always giving a certain function the same default arguments and optionally omit some arguments (like in C++), it's a bit more intricate. See [C default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1472138/c-default-arguments), including [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73934150/584518) late answer that I posted there recently myself.

Answer (score 1):

Another, not uncommon solution would be to use a function-like macro right away, e.g.

```
#define MY_FUNC_DEFAULTS() myFunc(10, 15, true)
```

This looks also fairly clean, retains the function syntax etc. Note that the macro expansion does not end with a semicolon so that it can (and must) be provided at the call site in the natural fashion: `if(cond) MY_FUNC_DEFAULTS(); else g();` works as expected.

Because you originally asked about C++: I find some of the OCD types here a bit annoying. All preprocessor solutions provided in the answers here work equally well in both languages. Nonetheless, the preprocessor is text replacement and as such inherently unsafe. Therefore, C++ provides means to avoid using it. In this case one could provide default arguments in the function declaration:

```
void myFunc(uint8_t temp = 10, uint32_t value = 15, bool valid = true);
```

This essentially overloads the function: It defines a set of four distinct functions that take 3, 2, 1 or 0 arguments, respectively. All of the calls

```
myFunc();
myFunc(1);
myFunc(1,2);
myFunc(1,2,false);
```

are now possible.

Such declarations could be present in different translation units with different default values. The default values are defined *at the caller side* and are not part of the function signature.  (Whether that would be recommended is debatable though.)

Comment: I really like this solution #define MY_FUNC_DEFAULTS() myFunc(10, 15, true)